# Azure AuthorizationFailed

Tags: python, sdk, azure-sdk-python

When i am  running python script to manage vm's on azure environment its getting failed due to **AuthorizationFailed** message. Following exception are getting printed along with the error message.

***CloudError("The client 'bdafca09-d426-4924-b63c-dff61c034187' with object id 'bdafca09-d426-4924-b63c-dff61c034187' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope '/subscriptions/49ec57ce-8a6f-4cdf-95bf-8163b231edf6/resourcegroups/azure-sample-group-virtual-machines' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.")***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Contributor` role for the application you created in Azure AD in the portal.

1. Select your subscription in **Subscriptions**(search Subscriptions
   in the top bar)

[image]

2. Add **role assignment** in **Access control**

[image]

3. select and add the Contributor role for your application.

[image]

4. If you add it successfully, you will see your application showing in the role assignment list.

[image]